# ¿Tabs Dinámicas Boostrap y jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Buenas Tengo una consulta al crear tabs dinámicamente con un ajax request. modifico el DOM y no las reconoce.

¿Hay alguna forma de que las renocozca?

```html
  echo "<ul class='nav nav-tabs'>";
      $contador= 0;
      foreach ($ListaSucursalesFO as $key => $val) {
        if ($contador == 0){
          echo "<li class='active'><a data-toggle='tab' href='#$val'>$val</a></li>";
        }else{
          echo"  <li><a data-toggle='tab' href='#$val'>$val</a></li>";
        }
        $contador++;
      }
  echo "  </ul>";
  echo "<div class='tab-content'>";
  $contador2 = 0;
  foreach ($ListaSucursalesFO as $key => $val) {
    if($contador2 == 0){
      echo " <div id='$val' class='tab-pane fade in active'>
                <h3>$val</h3>
                <p>Some content.</p>
              </div>
        ";
    }else{
      echo " <div id='$val' class='tab-pane fade'>
                <h3>$val</h3>
                <p>Some content.</p>
              </div>
        ";
    }
    $contador2 ++;
  }
  echo "</div>";
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Incluiste la librería `JQuery` mediante la etiqueta `script`? Todos los plugins de `Bootstrap` dependen de `JQuery`.

Comment: si... si  escribo las tabs normalmente funcionan . pero al crearlas diatónicamente no funcionan